# I cannot make it so data is stored in mysql database

Tags: php, html, mysql, database

So, I have a .php file that is meant to check that someone's username is available, and then store it in the database, the 'check' part works, and then redirects the user to the correct page, however, the data is not being stored in the database.

The form it refers to is from the file that the user clicks on to actually enable this .php file.

(I labelled the section of code that should store data in the mysql database)

```
<?php

$host="localhost"; 
$username="root";  
$password="___________"; 
$db_name="test_database"; 
$tbl_name="members";

mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect"); 
mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select DB");

$username=$_POST['username'];
$password=$_POST['password'];
$email=$_POST['email'];

$username = stripslashes($username);
$username = mysql_real_escape_string($username);
$sql="SELECT * FROM $tbl_name WHERE username='$username'";
$result=mysql_query($sql);

$count=mysql_num_rows($result);

// If result matched $myusernametable row must be 1 row
if($count==1){

header("location:register_failure.html");
}
else {
$username=$_POST['username'];//Start of code which should store data in database
$password=$_POST['password'];
$email=$_POST['email'];
$sql = "INSERT INTO members (username, password, email) VALUES ('$username',                                    
'$password', '$email')";//End of code which should store data in database
header("location:register_success.html");
}
?>
```

Comment: Have you checked for error messages from mysql? Have you echo'd out the query to make sure it is correct? What have you done to debug this?

Comment: You need to run the sql you created. `mysql_query($sql);`

Comment: You're creating the `INSERT` query, but not actually executing it.

Comment: _"//End of code which should store data in database"_: No it shouldn't. It just stores a query _expression_ in a string.

Comment: **Side note** Don't use `mysql_*()` - it's deprecated. Use `mysqli` or `PDO`. You are susceptible to SQL Injection attacks - you should escape all your inputs, or consider using prepared statements.

Comment: Thanks so much Nathan! It appears that was stupid on my part, sorry, I only started programming two days ago, just grasping any knowledge I can by reading and videos :)

Answer (score 1):

You've assigned the INSERT statement to run to $sql, but not actually run it. Add this line between the $sql assignment and the header statement:

```
$result=mysql_query($sql);
```

I'd also highly recommend adding some error checking in there. As it is now even if the query fails the user still gets redirected to the success page.

Answer (score 0):

replace your else command with this:

```
else {
$username=$_POST['username'];//Start of code which should store data in database
$password=$_POST['password'];

$email=$_POST['email'];

$addsql = "INSERT INTO members (username, password, email) VALUES ('$username', '$password', '$email')";
$dosql = mysql_query($addsql);
header("location:register_success.html");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i think it would be better, if you return the status of the executed sql statement like:

```
else {
$username=$_POST['username'];//Start of code which should store data in database
$password=$_POST['password'];
$email=$_POST['email'];
$sql = "INSERT INTO members (username, password, email) VALUES ('$username', '$password', '$email')";
$result = mysql_query(sql);
if (!$result) {
    die('SQL Error: ' . mysql_error());
}
header("location:register_success.html");
}
```

so the user knows, if the register was successfull or not ;)
you could also remove the "die" part and replace it with mail,
so you will be noticed if something is wrong with your signup.

Comment: Technically, I don't need the status, because it redirects the user to a file named; register_success.html which is actually a web page that tells them it's successful :)
But, thank you for replacing the die part, that will help me :P